# Force Vuetify text field value to update

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

In the below codesandbox I'm trying to implement multiple numeric inputs so that their combined total never goes more than `max`.

I have successfully implemented this on the item, and you can see in the Vue tools that the value passed to the `<v-text-field>` component is the correct value, but the rendered value keeps increasing beyond `max`.

I have tried creating a new object based on the old one so that the `Input` component recognises the changed prop and forces a re-render but this doesn't work. I've tried explicitly forcing a re-render of the component (and of the `v-text-field` itself by reference) but still no dice. Tried with and without `$nextTick` pretty much everywhere too...

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-worker-rho9wo?file=/components/Input.vue

EDIT: There is no `preventDefault` on the @input event as it's just raw text. `@change` only fires on focusing away from the field, by which time it will be too late. Conversely, trying to put the logic on a `@mousedown` or `@keydown` event will be too early as at that point the `event.target.value` is still the previous input.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end to achieve desired behaviour I had to extend the VTextField and override the `onInput` behaviour

```js
<script>
import { VTextField } from "vuetify/lib/components/VTextField";
export default {
  name: "MyTextField",
  extends: VTextField,
  methods: {
    onInput(e) {
      const target = e.target;
      this.$emit("input", target.value);
      this.$refs.input.blur();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-sammet-zr7qr0?file=/components/MyTextInput.vue:0-294

Comment: I see, that's one step further.

Answer (score 1):

Check this codesandox I forked from your project: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-72330576-custom-inputnumber-v-for-max-validation-9mvoed?file=/pages/index.vue

I already had made a custom InputNumber component in the past, so I just used mine instead, I hope that's okay. I just modify it a little bit to make it fit your requirements. Instead using the html input type number buttons, it would be better if you implement your own decrease/increase buttons, this way you gain more control over your input.

[image: Preview]

Comment: Sorry to be a stickler, but this is achieving the outcome by making the field read-only. Manual entry should continue to be allowed.

Comment: I got you. That required a bit more adjustments, but check the codesandbox again. You can also hide buttons with `hide-buttons` prop if you want. If an input exceeds the max value it's value gets reverted to it's previous one. I added some extra props to make them able to work as a whole.

Comment: Hmm, that still allows the user to type a number bigger. For example you can set `foo` to '123' and then it only reverts on clicking away.

Comment: What would be the expected behavior if the user starts typing 123?

Comment: Allow 1 but on trying to type 2 the field should not accept it and stay at 1

Comment: The crux is that in my CSB the logic is correctly blocking the value of the item from increasing once the maximum is reached, and that value is being supplied to the `v-text-field` as a prop but the number actually being displayed in the field is not reflecting that

Comment: Something that makes even less sense is in this CSB, on first input the field changes to 69 (expected behaviour), but then after that the value just changes as per the user input https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-wing-bfotj5?file=/pages/index.vue

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty because although you didn't achieve the desired behaviour you helped me eventually find the way to do it. Thanks for your input

Comment: My pleasure fam, thanks for the bounty.